# What is the correct order of these clauses while writing a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server

There are many clauses in SQL Server such as `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `HAVING`

What is the correct order of these clauses while writing a query?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question especially for quick referencing this. Not everyone writing an sql statement will know their order by heart forever. If you do then congratulations. As for searching, there is a lot of crap there and this is the top search result btw. Quite helpful I have to say. Especially as the answer quotes a reputable source compared to dozens of block entries which contain information that may or may not be true.

Comment: So Few Workers Go Home On time (Select From Where Group by Having Order by)

Comment: @Ryan, where does the JOIN clause fit in?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression>]

SELECT select_list [ INTO new_table ]

[ FROM table_source ] [ WHERE search_condition ]

[ GROUP BY group_by_expression ]

[ HAVING search_condition ]

[ ORDER BY order_expression [ ASC | DESC ] ]
```

Comment: @bleistift2 this question was specifically about Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL

Comment: I’m sorry. I’m just learning databases myself and was unaware of the difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
Groupby
Having
OrderBy
```

Or

```
SELECT
WHERE
OrderBy
```

Answer (score 0):

1. **SELECT**: This clause specifies the columns you want to retrieve from
   the database.
2. **FROM**: This clause specifies the tables from which you want to
   retrieve data.
3. **JOIN**: If you need to combine data from multiple tables, you use the
   JOIN clause to define the relationships between the tables.
4. **WHERE**: This clause filters the rows based on specific conditions.
5. **GROUP BY**: If you want to group the data based on certain columns,
   you use this clause.
6. **HAVING**: This clause filters the grouped rows based on conditions.
7. **ORDER BY**: This clause sorts the result set based on specified
   columns.
8. **LIMIT/OFFSET** (or FETCH): This clause is used to restrict the number
   of rows returned or to skip a certain number of rows.

```html
SELECT
    customers.customer_id,
    customers.first_name,
    customers.last_name,
    orders.order_date,
    order_items.product_id,
    order_items.quantity
FROM
    customers
JOIN
    orders ON customers.customer_id = orders.customer_id
JOIN
    order_items ON orders.order_id = order_items.order_id
WHERE
    customers.country = 'USA'
    AND orders.order_date >= '2023-01-01'
GROUP BY
    customers.customer_id
HAVING
    SUM(order_items.quantity) > 10
ORDER BY
    customers.last_name ASC,
    customers.first_name ASC
LIMIT 100;
```