# WHERE clause causes syntax error in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the tables (of a Bank):

Accounts

[image]

Clients

[image]

I want to return all the clients ID , of the clients that have more 
than one account in the bank

My suggestion :

```
SELECT c.Client_id_number , c.firstName_client , c.lastName_Client , COUNT(a.Account_number) as number_of_accounts
FROM Clients AS c
LEFT JOIN Accounts AS a
ON a.Client_id_number = c.Client_id_number
GROUP BY Client_id_number
WHERE number_of_accounts >= 2;
```

But the WHERE clause causes a syntax error . Why ?

Comment: `WHERE` must come before `GROUP BY`

Comment: @JohnConde: When I do that I get `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'number_of_accounts' in 'where clause'`

Comment: `where` clause cannot take aliases. `'number_of_accounts'` here is an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Client_id_number , c.firstName_client , c.lastName_Client , COUNT(a.Account_number) as number_of_accounts
FROM Clients AS c
LEFT JOIN Accounts AS a
ON a.Client_id_number = c.Client_id_number
GROUP BY Client_id_number
HAVING COUNT(a.Account_number) >= 2;
```

**[See this for correct SQL clasues order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654608/what-is-the-correct-order-of-these-clauses-while-writing-a-sql-query)**

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Account_number, Client_id_Number
FROM Accounts 
GROUP BY Account_number, Client_id_Number 
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Where clause should be before group by,

```
SELECT c.Client_id_number , c.firstName_client , c.lastName_Client , COUNT(a.Account_number) as number_of_accounts
FROM Clients AS c
LEFT JOIN Accounts AS a
ON a.Client_id_number = c.Client_id_number
WHERE number_of_accounts >= 2    
GROUP BY Client_id_number;
```

Comment: This causes to : `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'number_of_accounts' in 'where clause`
`

Comment: `number_of_accounts` is not a table column