# SQL statement complicated INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, mariadb, inner-join

In my database I have two tables:

```
user, columns: id, username
friends, columns: this_friend_id, that_friend_id
```

On my website, users can send each other friend requests, and when one user accepts the friend request of an other user, an entry in the `friends` table is made with the id of the user who sent the request in the column `this_friend_id` and another entry in the column `that_friend_id` with the user who accepted the friend request.

When a user is logged in to the page, the user should be able to see all users in a table, with all the users and whether he/she is a friend with him/her or not. But I'm not able to accomplish the second thing. It shouldn't matter whether the logged in user is in the `his_friend_id` column or in the `that_friend_id` column.

I want to select all friends of the user.

Here is what I've tried so far:
(for demonstration purposes I've picked the id = 3 for the user)

```
SELECT user.id, friends.this_friend_id, friends.that_friend_id
FROM friends
WHERE friends.this_friend_id = 3 OR friends.that_friend_id = 3
INNER JOIN user
ON friends.this_friend_id = user.id OR friends.that_friend_id = user.id;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: select from join ... join where [What is the correct order of these clauses while writing a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4654608/3404097)

Comment: Why did you make that edit? If it is an answer, it doesn't belong in a question post. Please do not edit posts in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers. If there are reasonable answers posted then ask a new question instead. Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. PS [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code & example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you've got the order of operators the wrong way around. The operator order of a simple query should be:

- SELECT
- FROM
- JOIN
- WHERE
- ORDER

So your query would turn into:

```
SELECT user.id, friends.this_friend_id, friends.that_friend_id 
FROM friends 
INNER JOIN user 
ON friends.this_friend_id = user.id 
OR friends.that_friend_id = user.id;
WHERE friends.this_friend_id = 3 
OR friends.that_friend_id = 3
```

However using or statements is not great as it causes full scans of tables. If you wanted to create a more performant script you could do the below, where you use the union statement instead of the or to get this_friend_id and that_friend_id join.

```
SELECT user.id, friends.this_friend_id, friends.that_friend_id 
FROM [friends] 
INNER JOIN [user] 
ON friends.this_friend_id = user.id 
WHERE friends.this_friend_id = 3 
union
SELECT user.id, friends.this_friend_id, friends.that_friend_id 
FROM [friends] 
INNER JOIN [user] 
ON friends.that_friend_id = user.id 
WHERE friends.that_friend_id = 3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: @cigien the affiliation was clearly stated, but since they were out of context links, not remotely relevant to the question or answer, I simply edited it out.

Comment: @miken32 Ah, it looks like OP added in the disclosure after my comment. But regardless, I think you're right, if the links aren't relevant, then editing them out is a better option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE clause goes *after* the JOIN clause(s):

```
SELECT user.id, friends.this_friend_id, friends.that_friend_id
FROM friends
INNER JOIN user
ON friends.this_friend_id = user.id OR friends.that_friend_id = user.id
WHERE friends.this_friend_id = 3 OR friends.that_friend_id = 3;
```

Comment: I searched that up and there stood that it doesn´t matter if I put the WHERE or the JOIN clause first but thank you i edited my post!